# passedData is not found in Host

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am new to Backend. I wonder why my data from JSON cannot be passed to the EJS Template. Terminal says 'subcontent is not found'

[image: File]

[image: JSON]

[image]

Comment: there is no subcontent variable in .ejs file. You should send data like res.render('*.ejs',{data:data})

Comment: on .ejs file you should use <%= data[0].title %> to access title